# How to use underscore.string's reverse() inside a chain?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, chaining

I am working with both underscore and underscore.string, and there is a conflict with the function `.reverse()` since both have a function with the same name.

To avoid conflict, we need to use `_.str` like this:

```
_.str.reverse("foobar"); //.reverse("foobar") won't work
```

However, don't know how to use the underscore.string's `.reverse()` inside a chain.

I have tried with the following:

```
var something=_.chain("hello world!")
        .capitalize()
        //_.str
        //_.str()
        //.str
        //.str()
        .reverse()
        .value();
```

But don't work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `_.mixin` to add the `_.str.reverse` function to the underscore object with another name so it doesn't clash with arrays' reverse:

```
_.mixin({strReverse: _.str.reverse});
var something = _.chain("hello world!").capitalize().strReverse().value();
console.log(something); // logs "!dlrow olleH"
```

And a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s6rje/), of course.

Note that after doing that `strReverse` will also be otherwise accessible in the underscore object:

```
console.log(_('hello').strReverse()); // logs "olleh"
```

Comment: Also you can checkout blogpost http://edtsech.github.com/blog/2011/11/09/underscore.string-2.0-release/

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `capitalize()` must support the next method in the chain, but it does not. It's a mistake to think you can somehow refer to another object's method by name inside the chain. It simply doesn't work that way. In short, you'll need to solve this another way.

Comment: I guess I will need to do it like `_.str.reverse(_.chain("hello world!").capitalize().value())`... I wanted to avoid this, but if I need to, I will